C OpenGL: Why is the triangle not being rendered
I know the shaders have linked together since i was following learnopengl.com and that example worked. Then when i tried to rewrite it and abstract a bit, it just stopped rendering to the screen. I also am not getting any errors in the console.
const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";

const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\0";


unsigned int compile_shader(const char *source, GLenum type) { 
    unsigned int shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    return shader;
}

unsigned int create_program() {
    unsigned int vertex_shader = compile_shader(vertexShaderSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    unsigned int fragment_shader = compile_shader(fragmentShaderSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);

    return program;
}

void setup_buffers(unsigned int *vao, unsigned int *vbo) {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, vao);
    glBindVertexArray(*vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vbo);

    // unbind vao and vbo
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void add_triangle(unsigned int vao, unsigned int vbo, float *vertices, GLenum usage) {
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, usage);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

void render_triangles(unsigned int program, unsigned int vao, unsigned int vbo) {
    glUseProgram(program);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

int main() {
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Test", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create GLFW window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialise GLAD\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // handles when the window resizes
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    unsigned int shader_program = create_program();
    unsigned int vao, vbo;
    setup_buffers(&vao, &vbo);

    // Triangle 1 vertices
    float triangle1[] = {
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // Top vertex
       -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // Bottom left vertex
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f    // Bottom right vertex
    };
    add_triangle(vao, vbo, triangle1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    printf("%lu\n", vbo);
    printf("%lu\n", vao);

    // Main program loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        process_input(window);

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        render_triangles(shader_program, vao, vbo);

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        GLenum error = glGetError();
        if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {
            printf("OpenGL error: %d\n", error);
        }
    }

    // Clean up and terminate GLFW
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

